# How to debug Android native C++ modules in Release mode?

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, native

I have an Android app with a native C++ module (.so) developed with VisualGDB and Visual Studio. In Debug mode I can debug both the Java code (with Android Studio) and the C++ code (with VS), and everything works fine.

In Release mode I get an error that could be easily understood if you could debug the code.

To compile in Release mode, I have to remove the android:debuggable="true" attribute from the Android.manifest, but in this case the VS command "Debug App with VisualGDB" fails because there is no gdb server in the package.

How to include the gdb server to the Release apk?